# separate certain properties from a scss file

Tags: sass

Anyone knows of any scss format tool that takes an existing scss file, and extracts  the chosen properties and saves them to a new file with the same structure? 
For example I want to remove all color and background references from my scss file and save it in a new one. therefore having kind of a layout.scss and color.scss.

Thanks

Comment: Watch this video all the way through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTBaQ2DcGUk&t=12s

Comment: ...didn't have anything to do with my question but thanks anyway.

Comment: Point was, you use more than 1 SCSS file. You put what you want separated in different files

Comment: Normally I would do that, thing is I have scss files created by someone else and I need to separate certain properties to a new scss file.